# Visual Studio 2012 SQL editor missing tool bar

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I have a number of SQL script files in a database project.  When I open some of them, the editor includes a toolbar, with options to connect to database, execute the script, etc.

However, when I open some of them, that toolbar is not shown, and there appears to be no way to execute the script.

How can I get that bar to appear?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A fix that seems to work for me is to change the Build Action to be "None" in the properties for the sql file in question.  Close and reopen the file, and voila there is the infamous connection toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the above answer means that Database Projects is rendered pointless. A better solution is to build your own bespoke toolbar using the toolbar controls and commands from the SQL Menu.

Comment: Can you explain how to do this?